# Look up next empty row and write data to it

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code that searches for MyVal variable and if not found it writes the data to the next empty column.

I found that comboboxes do not like horizontal lists so I have transposed all of my data to a vertical list.

How can I convert my code to search and write to next empty row instead of next empty column?

```vb
Sub Copy_To_Borrower_DBase()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim myVal As String
    Dim sourceRng As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    MyNote = Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value & " already exists, do you want to 
    overwrite?"
    myVal = Sheets("Main").Range("F5").Value ' dropdown list
    Set sourceRng = Worksheets("Borrower 
    Database").Range("5:5").Find(What:=myVal, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'locate column 
    where to copy from
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Borrower Database")

    If Not sourceRng Is Nothing Then
        Answer = MsgBox(MyNote, vbCritical + vbYesNo, "Overwrite??")
        If Answer = vbNo Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            With ws2
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Cells(5, sourceRng.Column).Value = ws1.Range("F5").Value 'Borrower Name
                .Range(.Cells(6, sourceRng.Column), .Cells(8, sourceRng.Column)).Value = 
                ws1.Range("G6:G8").Value 'Income, Credit Pmt and Car Pmt
                .Range(.Cells(9, sourceRng.Column), .Cells(10, sourceRng.Column)).Value 
                = ws1.Range("G11:G12").Value 'Ratios
                .Cells(11, sourceRng.Column).Value = ws1.Range("G15").Value 'Reserves
                .Cells(12, sourceRng.Column).Value = ws1.Range("D15").Value 'Credit Score
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End With
        End If
    Else
        With ws2
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            lCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Column
            .Cells(5, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("F5").Value 'Borrower Name
            .Range(.Cells(6, lCol), .Cells(8, lCol)).Value = 
            ws1.Range("G6:G8").Value 'Income, Credit Pmt and Car Pmt
            .Range(.Cells(9, lCol), .Cells(10, lCol)).Value = 
            ws1.Range("G11:G12").Value 'Borrower Name
            .Cells(11, lCol).Value = ws1.Range("G15").Value 'Reserves
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)
[image]

Comment: I took a screenshot of what the data looks like, the rows and columns may not match my code but the location of the data in the screenshot is correct.

Comment: I would like the code to detect the next empty row (in the sample it is row 8) and then I want to write the data in that row using the .cells command where I would combine it with the correct row and column to write each different piece of data.

Comment: That is the output, the user enters data on another sheet ("Main") in the workbook and if the user wants to save the data he clicks on a macro button to write the data to the "Borrower Database" sheet, the code writes it to the next available row. In this case a new entry would be written starting at range B8 since it is the next available row.

Comment: Can you show how your database sheet setup looks like? If so I will write up a solution

Comment: Urdearboy, the screenshot is the database sheet. The code searches for the next empty row in the "Borrower Database" column B, then writes writes data from the sheet called "Main" to the sheet called "Borrower Database". I need to know how to write the code to search for the next empty row in the "Borrower Database" sheet on column B, once I find that I can write the .values from the "Main" Sheet using the .cells.value commands.

Comment: Impossible to read. Please, re-format your code.

Comment: @JohnyL what do you mean? How should I format it?

Comment: Format your code means to indent it properly.

Comment: Thank you all for the help I was finally able to accomplish my goal utilizing the following code: lRow2 = .Cells(6, 3).End(xlDown).Row + 1
and .Cells(lRow2, 3).Value = ws1.Range("F5").Value